# send().catch() doesn't give me the error message anymore

Tags: web3js, truffle, metamask

I'm using Truffle/Drizzle/MetaMask and calling methods with `send()` and using `.then()` and `.catch()` and I rely on getting the error message send to `.catch()` e.g.

```
contract.methods['hello'](arg).send({
    from: drizzle.web3.eth.accounts.givenProvider.selectedAddress
})
.then(() =>

    // do good stuff

)
.catch((error) => {

    const message = error.message;

    // display a nice message to the user

}
```

to do things like tell the difference between the user cancelling the transaction and throwing "User denied transaction signature" vs my contract throwing a revert message (and which one) or a nonce mismatch so I can display a more helpful message in the UI.

However, `error.message` no longer gives me anything, all I get is `Internal JSON-RPC error.` no matter what the error.

Is this a change in MetaMask or Web3? It was working the last time I worked on my DApp a month ago.

How do I tell the difference between user cancel vs a revert message vs nonce mismatch, and how do I read the revert message thrown by the contract?

Comment: Perhaps you were testing against ganache previously.

Comment: I'm still using Ganache. I forgot to mention. I'm running `ganache-cli`